# Generalization of a windowing function for n-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, windowing

I have `a` n-dimensional array I want to apply a windowing function to. In short, I need to construct a `window` function for each dimension and multiply it to the `a` array. For example, I first construct the window function for the first dimension, stack it for the remaining dimensions and multiply it point-wise to the array `a`. I sequentially do this for all the array dimensions.

I have been able to do so by accounting for the dimensions of the array in a conditional structure such as `if a.ndim == 1: ... elif a.ndim == 2: ...` and so on. Here is a MCVE with the non-generalized version that does this (examples are 1D and 3D arrays):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

def window_ndim(a, wfunction):
    """
    Performs an in-place windowing on N-dimensional data.
    This is done to mitigate boundary effects in the FFT.
    :param a: Input data to be windowed, modified in place.
    :param wfunction: 1D window generation function. Example: scipy.signal.hamming
    :return: windowed a
    """
    if a.ndim == 1:
        return a * wfunction(len(a))
    elif a.ndim == 2:
        window0 = wfunction(a.shape[0])
        window1 = wfunction(a.shape[1])
        window0 = np.stack([window0] * a.shape[1], axis=1)
        window1 = np.stack([window1] * a.shape[0], axis=0)
        a *= window0*window1
        return a
    elif a.ndim == 3:
        window0 = wfunction(a.shape[0])
        window1 = wfunction(a.shape[1])
        window2 = wfunction(a.shape[2])
        window0 = np.stack([window0] * a.shape[1], axis=1)
        window0 = np.stack([window0] * a.shape[2], axis=2)
        window1 = np.stack([window1] * a.shape[0], axis=0)
        window1 = np.stack([window1] * a.shape[2], axis=2)
        window2 = np.stack([window2] * a.shape[0], axis=0)
        window2 = np.stack([window2] * a.shape[1], axis=1)
        a *= window0*window1*window2
        return a
    else: raise ValueError('Wrong dimensions')

np.random.seed(0)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
a = np.random.rand(2,3,4)
# [[[0.55 0.72 0.6  0.54]
#   [0.42 0.65 0.44 0.89]
#   [0.96 0.38 0.79 0.53]]

#  [[0.57 0.93 0.07 0.09]
#   [0.02 0.83 0.78 0.87]
#   [0.98 0.8  0.46 0.78]]]
a_windowed = window_ndim(a, signal.hamming)
# [[[2.81e-04 3.52e-03 2.97e-03 2.79e-04]
#   [2.71e-03 3.98e-02 2.70e-02 5.71e-03]
#   [4.93e-04 1.89e-03 3.90e-03 2.71e-04]]

#  [[2.91e-04 4.56e-03 3.50e-04 4.46e-05]
#   [1.29e-04 5.13e-02 4.79e-02 5.57e-03]
#   [5.01e-04 3.94e-03 2.27e-03 4.00e-04]]]

a = np.random.rand(10) # [0.12 0.64 0.14 0.94 0.52 0.41 0.26 0.77 0.46 0.57]
a_windowed = window_ndim(a, signal.hamming) # [0.01 0.12 0.07 0.73 0.51 0.4  0.2  0.36 0.09 0.05]
```

My **goal** is to generalize this conditional structure so I do not need to check the dimensions case of the array. Something like `for axis, axis_size in enumerate(a.shape):...` would be more elegant and account for a n-dimensional array, instead of just 1, 2 or 3 dimensions. My attempt has involved something with `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice` consisting of

```
axis_idxs = np.arange(len(a.shape))
the_cycle = cycle(axis_idxs)
for axis, axis_size in enumerate(a.shape):
    axis_cycle = islice(the_cycle, axis, None)
    next_axis = next(axis_cycle)
    window = wfunction(axis_size)
    window = np.stack([window]*a.shape[next_axis], axis=next_axis)
    ...
    a *= window
return a
```

But never got very far since for `a.ndim == 3` is difficult to construct the window function from the second axis as I first need to stack for the first axis first and then last axis, contrary to the other window functions (first and last axis) where I stack sequentially on the following axis by cycling through `axis_cycle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to generalize it for a n-dimensional array by always start stacking the `window` array on the first dimension and skipping the stacking operation on the own axis.

```
def window_ndim(a, wfunction):
    for axis, axis_size in enumerate(a.shape):
        window = wfunction(axis_size)
        for i in range(len(a.shape)):
            if i == axis:
                continue
            else:
                window = np.stack([window] * a.shape[i], axis=i)
        a *= window
    return a
```

This returns the same result for a 1D, 2D or 3D array as showed in the question MCVE test cases.